# Security issues with Web Services and SSRS

Tags: security, ssrs

I have a developer who would like to interact with the web services on the SSRS server. The way I understand it is that they would like to populate a list of reports in a folder so that the user can select which one they'd like to view.

My initial thought is that this gets around any type of security that is setup on the folders themselves.

Does anyone have any experience with this and could maybe think of something I am not considering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you connect to the SSRS webservice you have to authenticate with a valid SSRS user.

If you connect to the webservice as the same user that is viewing the list of reports you will only see the reports that user has access to.

You can also use the [ReportingService2005.GetPolicies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.getpolicies.aspx) to get the permissions of a report server item.

Comment: Yea, we've been back and forth on it. The program is going to have to handle what reports they can see. It's a product of how they are doing it.